# redirect public_html folder to production folder

Tags: php, public-html

I have a local project on my pc, that I have uploaded in a Hosting in GoDaddy.

```
public_html/production/index.php
public_html/includes/conection_DB.php
```

In order to access my webpage I have to write in the url:
`example.com/production/index.php`

It works fine, but is there a way to configure something in GoDaddy or in PHP in order that the url show: `example.com/index.php`

Comment: Not sure what all is in the connection_DB.php file but I’m guessing that file should be outside of your public html folder.

Comment: this is probably too specific to GoDaddy.  Maybe try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file and add the following

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /production
```

the above should redirect any traffic from exapmle.com to example.com/production